How to implement "dependent join" symbol in latex?
in pdf <<The Complete Story of Joins (in HyPer)>> introduce a new join type: dependent join, but how to implement this join symbol in latex?


The symbol is available through stix2, but I really don't like most of the provided fonts.
If you want Times as the main font, you can just import the symbol.
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{newtx}

% load the required fonts
\DeclareFontEncoding{LS1}{}{}
\DeclareFontSubstitution{LS1}{stix2}{m}{n}

\NewDocumentCommand{\lfbowtie}{}{%
  \mathbin{\text{\usefont{LS1}{stix2frak}{m}{n}\symbol{"C0}}}%
}
\NewDocumentCommand{\rfbowtie}{}{%
  \mathbin{\text{\usefont{LS1}{stix2frak}{m}{n}\symbol{"C1}}}%
}
\RenewDocumentCommand{\bowtie}{}{%
  \mathbin{\text{\usefont{LS1}{stix2scr}{m}{n}\symbol{"0E}}}%
}
\NewDocumentCommand{\fbowtie}{}{%
  \mathbin{\text{\usefont{LS1}{stix2frak}{m}{n}\symbol{"C2}}}%
}


\begin{document}

\[
T_1 \lfbowtie T_2 =
\{t_1\circ t_2 \mid t_1\in T_1 \land t_2\in T_2(t_1) \land p(t_1\circ t_2)\}
\]

\[
T_3 \bowtie T_2 \rfbowtie T_1 \fbowtie T_0
\]

\end{document}


You don't really need newtx, of course.
If you prefer stix2, then the \Declare... lines should be omitted, but the symbols should be redeclared as \mathbin, because the default is \mathrel which seems not to reflect the present usage.
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{stix2}

\begingroup
\def\reltobin#1{\expanded{\global\mathchardef#1=\inteval{#1-"1000}}}
\reltobin\lfbowtie
\reltobin\rfbowtie
\reltobin\fbowtie
\reltobin\bowtie
\endgroup

\begin{document}

\[
T_1 \lfbowtie T_2 =
\{t_1\circ t_2 \mid t_1\in T_1 \land t_2\in T_2(t_1) \land p(t_1\circ t_2)\}
\]

\[
T_3 \bowtie T_2 \rfbowtie T_1 \fbowtie T_0
\]

\end{document}



Maybe import the \bowtie symbol also for consistency since the glyph is so different.

Thanks you very much!

@lichuang See the edit

@SandyG Definitely needed!
